# Error while adding mp4parser library to a project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, mp4parser

I'm trying to use [mp4parser library](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) in my project.  My android studio version is 1.0.2.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. I've downloaded mp4parser zipfile from the link: https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser
2. I've extracted the zip file to MyProjectName/app/libraries
3. Renamed the folder to mp4parser
4. Add this line of code to settings.gradle file:

   ```
   include ':app:libraries:mp4parser'
   ```
5. Add this line of code to build.gradle (in dependencies block):

   compile project('libraries:mp4parser')

Now I want to sync the project with gradle files. This error pops up:

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

I don't have this problem with other libraries. Seems that its only mp4parser that I have problem with. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're including the library as source, the best thing to do is to unpack it somewhere and import it as a module.

The error you're getting is cryptic but it means that the build system is looking for a **build.gradle** file at that location and not finding it (or it doesn't see an `apply plugin` statement in the file telling it what to do). I'm assuming that the library you're trying to use doesn't have a Gradle build script.

If you import the library using the Android Studio UI, a build script will be generated for the module and you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you man , seems that import module is the right way to add these kinda libraries that dont have buil.gradle files .